# Как в JS форме отправлять на email только выбранные чекбоксы

Tags: javascript, html, php

Есть сайт на Joomla, есть компонент форм FormCalc. Форма с калькулятором, в общем нужно после того как юзер выбрал то что нужно, поставил галочки, и при нажатии кнопки отправить приходило письмо именно с этими чекбоксами, которые он выбрал.

Форма на HTML и JS. Sql не участвует.

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: FormCalc - ужасный компонент. Был тут [вопрос][1], такую кашу варить оч сложно, пишите лучше свою форму.

[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/99431/привязать-картинку-к-селекту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Устанавливаете атрибут name для чекбоксов вида array[] (name="array[]") и тогда на странице, куда отправляется форма можно будет отловить в $_REQUEST этот массив, который будет содержать значения всех отмеченных чекбоксов

Comment: Можно по подробней про отлов массива через $_REQUEST